# update datetime field in model form only shows plain text instead datepicker Django

Tags: django, datetime, datetime-format

I'm trying to update my `DateTimeField` field , but it only shows a plain text of numbers instead of the date picker

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    date= models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    #others
```

forms.py

```
class UpdateMyModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    date= forms.DateTimeField(required=True,input_formats=['%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M','%Y-%m-%dT%H:M%Z'],widget=forms.DateTimeInput(attrs={'type':'datetime'}))

class Meta:
    model = MyModel
    fields = ['date','others]
```

when i use `forms.DateTimeField` it doesnt show the previous date which i've selected before! and when i remove `forms.DateTimeField` it only show a plain text `type=text` i also tried to use

```
class DateInput(forms.DateInput):
    input_type = 'date'
```

but it shows only show `Y-m-d` : year-month-day i have to display hour and minute as well ? is there something else i have to change please

Answer (score 2):

First of all, I recommend you to use
`date = forms.DateTimeInput(attrs={'type': 'datetime-local'})` in your forms.py

Secondly, if you want to see the previous date, add a [datefilter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/templates/builtins/#date) in your template.
for example:
`<span>Date:</span><input class="mt-4 ml-4" type="datetime-local" name="date" value="{{form.date.value | date:'c'}}"  id="id_deadline_date">`
the date filter that will help is `| date:'c'`
after these changes, I think you will be able to see the previous date.
I have explained why you should use a date filter in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66648392/django-update-view-not-showing-date-input-previous-values).